# Allow filter in cassandra query

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have one table

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    p1 int,
    p2 int,
    created_at timestamp,
    user_name text,
    c1 text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((p1, p2),user_name)
) WITH additional_write_policy = '99p';
```

what will happen if i will run query

`select * from user where p1 = 1 and p2 = 1 and user_name = 'abc' allow filtering;`

will allow filtering will work here or it's just redundant in query .

Answer (score 2):

Since you're filtering by the primary key columns, `ALLOW FILTERING` is redundant. When you filter by partition key and (optionally) clustering column(s), the coordinator will know which replicas store the data, and each of the contacted replicas will infer through local indexing where the data is stored at the storage level, making it an efficient Cassandra read query.

In opposition, when the `ALLOW FILTERING` query doesn't filter by all terms of the partition key, and/or filters by non-primary key columns, local replica indexing and/or global indexing will be rendered useless, making it so that a large set of replicas scan their full dataset and filter after reading - thus inefficient.

The purpose of the `ALLOW FILTERING` option is to exceptionally allow queries that require a full scan, since this type of query fails by default, as a safeguard, due to the impact risks.

Answer (score 2):

Some basics: One should never use `ALLOW FILTERING` in your read queries as that is a bad practice because of the following reasons,

1. This table data model is not designed appropriately based on the application access pattern
2. AF will perform a scan of the entire distributed table

Having said that, it *may be* okay here in this scenario as you're already providing the full primary keys [partition keys + clustering keys] of the table here and it'd be a no-op for AF.

Comment: ya i am not using but simply asked in the above case . thanks for information

Comment: As long as the partition is *not* so big, one could leverage `ALLOW FILTERING` just within the full partition. Example, if you've a `PRIMARY KEY((p1, p2), c1, c2)` and it *may be* okay to perform `SELECT <> FROM <> WHERE p1 = ? AND p2 = ? AND c2 > ? ALLOW FILTERING;` (without specifying `c1` here in this case) -- as it will only perform an entire scan within the partition and not the entire table and thus less inefficient when compared to not using all the partition keys at all.